# Path aliasing for static resources in Spring dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Web app where the dispatcher servlet is only used for static files. There also is a Jersey servlet for API calls from JavaScript, mapped on another URL pattern, not too relevant to my problem.

At the moment my entire dispatcher configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class DispatcherConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/www/");
    }
}
```

There is a `main.html` file right under `www` in my classpath. If a request comes in for `/main.html`, the file is served correctly. Great.

Now, I would like this same file to be returned for requests on `/`, `/part` and a bunch other paths. Basically, I want some kind of path aliasing here, or direct mapping from path to file. How can I achieve it?

Comment: It might be easier to use a `@RequestMapping` method with multiple `value` paths.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis With a `@Controller`? I don't even have (or want) any controllers.

Comment: Can't you just use your servlet container's _default servlet_ for serving static?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `default` servlet of the container to serve the `static resources`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the mapping from path to file can be defined with this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class DispatcherConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/pathToStatic").setViewName("/static.html");
    }
...

}
```

The above mapping will forward a request for `/pathToStatic` to the static view `static.html`.